# Реализовать приложение на python с помощью фреймворка

Tags: python, sql, django

У меня есть приложение на пайтоне с использованием sqlite, но без фреймворков. Мне нужно как-то реализовать веб-сервер, используя мое приложение и любой фреймворк пайтона и докер. Так же например тот же джанго использует ORM, а у меня в приложении sql запросы к бд. Вопрос как это все реализовать или совместить?

Comment: Можно обойтись и без ORM

Comment: а вместо вьюх что использовать? мои модули функции? и нужен ли здесь джанго ?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что же в итоге требуется? Если нужно к приложению прикрутить сервер, что бы приложение выдавало что-то в виде ответов на клиентские браузеры, то лучше использовать микрофреймворки, которые дают базовый функционал. Самый популярный - Flask. Его будет достаточно, что бы сделать обвязку вокруг приложения: роутинг и шаблонизация есть из коробки и гораздо компактнее, нежели в Django